# Is this a good argument against time travel?

Tags: fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, time-travel, bosons, identical-particles

Two fermions in two different points of space cannot be made to exist in the same point of space. It follows then that two fermions in two different times cannot be made to exist in the same time. 
However, if this rule holds:
Since bosons can be made to exist in the same place simultaneously (light beams passing through each other being an example), might they then also be able to circumvent this rule?

Comment: "It follows ..." No, it doesn't. The Pauli exclusion principle is more complicated than that.

Comment: First sentence is incorrect. Two fermions cannot occupy the same quantum state. Not the same thing.

Comment: So particles with mass can pass through each other? Really?

Answer (score 3):

> Two fermions in two different points of space cannot be made to exist in the same point of space.

This is a mischaracterization of the superselection rule. The idea is that a state starts out antisymmetric under exchange of identical fermions and since they are identical the state stays antisymmetric under interchange of identical fermions. So it only really comes up when a new fermion is created.

So the exclusion of being in the same state simply requires that when you make a new fermion, the new one has to be in a different state than existing fermions that are identical.

So when you excite the electron-positron field to have an additional electron for instance then it better be new in state as well as new in number. And this is enforced at a deep level, the fock space only allows no occupancy or single occupancy.

For bosons the rock space allows multiple occupancy and so when creating a new boson you don't have to worry y about being excluded but instead you do have to worry about being symmetric under exchange of identical fermions. And then it is also a superselection rule, since they start out symmetric under interchange of identical bosons, and since they are identical, they stay symmetric.

So if you are doing quantum field theory and describing things in terms of creation and annihilation you have to worry about it. Otherwise, it happens automatically since it only applies to identical particles.

> It follows then that two fermions in two different times cannot be made to exist in the same time.

This is not an implication. You can make a theory where two particles can not be at the same location (quantum mechanics doesn't have locations, but you can make theories that do) yet can be at the same time.

If you see five electrons at a single time this just means the single electron-positron field is in a non vacuum state with five modes of the field excited. They don't come with labels. You can't tell which is which, there is a field with five excitations, like a guitar string that is vibrating with two notes at the same time which individually would have different numbers of nodes. You can't label the modes as if they were something other than just a mode of excitation of a single object.

Identical means identical, it means they have to be modes of a unified object, because they can't have their own individuality.

> might [bosons] then also be able to circumvent this rule?

There isn't a rule, it doesn't even make sense to say the same particle is at two different places or at two different times. At any time you either have zero or one fermion in a particular mode (or a superposition of those options). And at any time you have some nonnegative integer number of bosons in a particular mode (or a superposition of those options).  You don't get to assign names to these individual excitation, in a sense they aren't individuals, so you can't even talk about there being the same one at a different time. The mode might be excited or not, it might have multiple excitations if it is a boson. But it isn't populated with an individual, that would betray the whole idea of identical particles.